# Comparing two different solutions to a quiz

Tags: python, algorithm

I've been going through a course on CS on Udemy, and got a quiz to solve.

Here's what is says:

> Define a procedure, find_last, that takes as input two strings, a
> search string and a target string, and returns the last position in
> the search string where the target string appears, or -1 if there are
> no occurrences.
>
> **Example**: `find_last('aaaa', 'a')` returns 3

The first solution is mine, the last is theirs. My question is, in what ways is theirs better than mine, and how could I think next time when solving this kind of a problem, so I would come to a solution faster and better. (I've spent at least 45 min thinking of a solution).

```
def find_last(s, t):
    some = s.find(t)
    i = some
    while s.find(t, i) != -1:
        some=s.find(t, i)
        i=i+1
   return some

def find_last(s,t):
    last_pos = -1
    while True:
        pos = s.find(t, last_pos+1)
        if pos==-1:
            return last_pos
        last_pos = pos
```

Here are the examples:

```
print find_last('aaaa', 'a') # returns 3
print find_last('aaaaa', 'aa') # returns 3
print find_last('aaaa', 'b') # returns -1
print find_last("111111111", "1") # returns 8
print find_last("222222222", "") # returns 9
print find_last("", "3") # returns -1
print find_last("", "") # returns 0
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/   Try this.

Comment: Before jumping to codereview please ensure you carefully read their [guide](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on how to stay on-topic.

Comment: How can you learn faster? Code more. Literally sit on stackoverflow and read questions and answers. If there's a problem, try to solve it yourself (you don't even need to post the answer, I personally love doing this while I'm bored at work). Practice makes perfect, most of the people with 500+ reps has been doing this for years.

Answer (score 4):

No need to code anything, just use python built-in string "right find":

```
print('aaaa'.rfind('a'))
```

result: 3

```
print('bbbbb'.rfind('a'))
```

result: -1

also works for "more-than-1-char" search strings of course

```
print('bbbxb'.rfind('bx'))
```

result: 2

Of course, in most widespread platforms like Linux or Windows, the processing is native: means you can't beat the speed.

Edit: someone kindly suggested to code your `find_last` in one line. Very nice:

```
find_last = lambda x,y: x.rfind(y)
```

Comment: What no `sum` this time?

Comment: @MooingRawr no need :) I thought of you today someone used sum with default `[]` again and it wasn't me :) (sorry, private joke!)

Comment: For clarity, `find_last = lambda x,y: x.rfind(y)`

Comment: @cricket_007 smart! maybe the author of the quiz didn't know about `rfind` :)

Answer (score 1):

I think **the main idea of the course is to learn algorithms** and this exercise is  good to start with (*regardless if the solution is not the most efficient way to resolve such problems in a current programming language*). So, their solution is better because they 'jump' during iteration, and you steps by 1, after you found index of first occurrence of `t`. I will try to explain with simple example:

You have got a string `s = 'abbbabbba'` and you need to find `'a'`. When you use your function, let it be `fun_last_1(s, 'a')`:

```
def find_last_1(s, t):
    some = s.find(t)           # some = 0
    i = some                   # i = 0
    while s.find(t, i) != -1:  # ok
        some=s.find(t, i)      # you again start from 0 (some = 0) ???
        i=i+1                  # and from here you steps by 1
                               # put print(i) in this row 
    return some                # in total you will have 9 iterations
```

you will need 9 iterations to achieve final result in this case. While they need only 4, lets add a print statement inside their loop:

```
def find_last_2(s,t):
    last_pos = -1                   
    while True:                     
        pos = s.find(t, last_pos+1) 
        print(pos)                   # add print here
        if pos==-1:                 
            return last_pos         
        last_pos = pos               # here they jumps

>>> find_last_2(s,'a')
0
4
8
-1

# and of course it will return 8
```

You can also add this debuggy `print()` inside the loop in your function and compare:

```
>>> find_last_1(s, 'a')
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

# and of course it will return 8
```

Hope this will help you to understand the difference.